# How to match the content in a pair of brackets, no matter how many pairs of brackets are contained in the content?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I want to replace

```
GD[many[[brackets]]], GD[evenMore[[[[brackets]]]]]
```

with

```
GD[someStuff], GD[someOtherStuff]
```

How can I match the correct pair of brackets? These patterns are scattered in a large document and might be enclosed in other brackets. The only way to identify them is through the prefix `GD` followed by a left bracket `[`. In the first place, I wanted to use `:%s` but could not find a solution to identify the pairing right bracket `]`.

Comment: Sounds tricky - but might be doable with `:help searchpair`. I'd think you'd need to write a function using this that replaces stuff inside the outermost brackets (if that's worth the time for you).

Comment: The other option would be to use a macro, and take advantage of the `ci]` normal mode command with the cursor positioned in the right place to target the pairs of brackets that you care about. Question: do the brackets that you care about always have `GD` right before them?

Comment: There are much more such patterns in my document. So it is not a good option to replace them one by one. In the first place, I want to use :%s/pattern/replace/g, and GD is a prefix in this case that I can take advantage of. The brackets I want to match is not the outermost in a line. There are more brackets enclosing the pattern shown here.

Comment: If there are more brackets enclosing the pattern, then you might want to edit the Q to reflect this (it might have an impact in how people try and solve the problem). Also, does each line have the same number of `GD[` occurrences? With a macro, you would only need to do the work once, and then run the macro on all lines with `:%norm @q` (assuming you recorded into the `q` register). I have a feeling that the `:%s` way might not have the power to 'know' which brackets are paired (I could be wrong).

Comment: There is no restriction other than the presence of `GD[`. Your suggestion is very inspiring. I didn't know of the existence of `norm`. Using this and `ci[` should solve my problem. I have written a python script to tackle it, but could try it next time when having similar problems. Thanks!

Comment: `:norm` is really great - you can even make it only run the commands on lines that match a pattern with `:g/pattern/norm <your commands here>` or only on lines that don't match with `:g!/pattern/norm <your commands here>`. The `:g` + `:norm` commands solve so many problems!

Comment: You said the only way to identify this pattern is through the prefix `GD`. Can you also rely on EOL and `,` as shown in this example? If so, something like this could be helpful: `%s/GD\[.\{-}\(,\|$\)/GD[stuff]\1/g`. It is also not clear from your question if you can replace `someStuff`, `someOtherStuff` after removing the inner brackets from your text.

Comment: What I showed here might not be a good example. Any thing other than EOL may present in the brackets `GD[]`, and every thing could present outside the brackets. There is no general rule that can be applied on the trailing byte.

Comment: I would start with `/GD[/e` + `nc%`, but I agree the question is unclear: how do we determine what to do with `someStuff`? Another idea: `/GD[/e`, `v%:s/\%V/[stuff]`, `n&`

Comment: The content varies as for different `GD[content]`. So it is considered as a whole in such replacement. In my case, it needs to be reusable. Using `c%` and `\%V` attaches the brackets to the content and thus requires other steps to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the solution of @Mattb is probably the better.

But for the sake of completion here is an attempt to provide an answer purely based on regular expression.

To match `GD[many]` you can use:

```
/\vGD\[[^\[\]]*\]
```

To match `GD[many]` or `GD[foo[bar]many[foo]bar]`

```
\vGD\[[^\[\]]*(\[[^\[\]]*\][^\[\]]*)*\]
```

To match `GD[many]` or `GD[foo[bar]many[foo]bar]` or `GD[foo[bar[many]foo]bar]`

```
\vGD\[[^\[\]]*(\[[^\[\]]*\][^\[\]]*)*(\[[^\[\]]*(\[[^\[\]]*\][^\[\]]*)*\][^\[\]]*(\[[^\[\]]*\][^\[\]]*)*)*\]
```

Here is a recursive function that return the expression that match the 'inside' depending of the number of bracket that you want to allow.

```
function! SearchExpression(n)
  if a:n==0
    return '[^\[\]]*'
  else
    let expression = SearchExpression(a:n - 1)
    return expression . '(\[' . expression . '\]' . expression . ')*'
  endif
endfunction
```

You can use it in search mode:

```
:exe '/\vGD\[' . SearchExpression(2) . '\]'
```

Or in substitute mode:

```
:exe '/\vGD\[' . SearchExpression(1) . '\]/someStuff/'
:exe '/\vGD\[' . SearchExpression(2) . '\]/someOtherStuff/'
```